# Cocoa Framework for 32bit guide

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks

I need to create a framework to be used by other developers in their Mac apps. One of the devs requires that his app be 32bit compatible.

From what I have read this would need me to create a 32bit Framework too. I am following [Apple's Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1) to create framework.

Most of my existing code uses ARC and I see that ARC cannot be used when compiling for 32bit :[ What are my alternatives besides rewriting all classes without ARC? Also is there is a Framework creation guide targeting 32bit compatibility?

Comment: Tell that developer that you cannot support him as it's too much work for too little gain. There is no reason to support 32-bit OSX these days given 64-bit was introduced in 10.6 (5 versions ago).

Comment: Agreed.  This is just a shade beyond "one of the devs requires that his app run on PowerPC machines."  :->

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for the input. I am trying to get this requirement changed too. But I want to keep this question open in case someone has an interesting input.